# Хочу из одной таблицы 100% получить данные, а из второй в зависимости от наличия

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица со значениями и внешняя таблица с диапазонами `(min, max)`. И диапазон может быть не указан. Но вот из головной таблицы данные нужно вытянуть в любом случае.

То есть можно в принципе сделать как 2 запроса, можно использовать `COALESCE`.

Какой путь более правильный?

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то? Что вы получить хотите?

Comment: хочу из одной таблицы 100% получить данные, а из второй в зависимости от наличия

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   Select t1.value, COALESCE(t2.min,0)
    from table t1
    left join table2 t2 on t2.value_id=t1.id
```

по моему с COALESCE более правильно

Comment: а как быть если много таблиц? все через join писать?

Comment: в вашем примере это тоже самое что  inner join т.е попадают записи ключи которых есть в обоих таблицах
в случае если надо брать все значение из первой нужно использовать left join. Почитайте там более подробно описано https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.value,t2.min
FROM talble t1 LEFT JOIN talbe t2 ON t2.value_id = t1.id
```

если диапазон не указан, t2.min будет равен null

Comment: а если несколько таблиц?

Comment: Вам надо про join почитать  [ссылка] (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Answer (score 0):

Если диапазон то

```
 Select .... 
from table t1 
left join t2 on t1.id between t2.min_id and t2.max_id
```

Проверить заджойнился ли диапазон можно так -  t2.id is not null